# How to control the map colors in mapview (package) in R?

Tags: r, r-mapview

I'm working with **R** as a *GIS* software, thanks to the *mapview*,*gstat*,*sp* and other packages.

I plot the result with `mapView()` function

```
m <- vgm(psill=.49,model="Sph",range=600000,nugget=3.8)
idw <- krige(formula = temp~1, locations = data_test, newdata = grd, model=m)
idw.output = as.data.frame(idw)
names(idw.output)[1:3] <- c("long", "lat", "temp")
coordinates(idw.output) <- ~long+lat
morocco <- readOGR("/opt/lampp/htdocs/ardusky/public/data/TNG", "TNG")
proj4string(idw.output)<-proj4string(morocco)
tempData <- idw.output[morocco,]
proj4string(data_test)<-proj4string(morocco)
gridded(tempData) <- TRUE
m<-mapView(tempData, zcol = "temp") + data_test
m
```

*result*:

[image]

I want to control the coloration, 0->blue 50->red for example.

there is any way to do that ?

Comment: Post code .... not pictures.

Comment: there is no code to show man, only one function witch is : mapView(tempData, zcol = "temp")

Comment: just a SpatialPixelsDataFrame

Comment: > summary(tempData)
Object of class SpatialPixelsDataFrame
Coordinates:
        min    max
long -5.991 -5.741
lat  35.575 35.811
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string :
[+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0]
Number of points: 8833
Grid attributes:
     cellcentre.offset cellsize cells.dim
long            -5.990    0.002       125
lat             35.576    0.002       118
Data attributes:
      temp      
 Min.   :22.91  
 1st Qu.:22.91  
 Median :22.91  
 Mean   :22.91  
 3rd Qu.:22.91  
 Max.   :22.91

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to `spplot` the `at` argument in `mapview` is what you want to use:

```
library(mapview)
library(sp)

data(meuse.grid)
coordinates(meuse.grid) <- ~x+y
proj4string(meuse.grid) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
gridded(meuse.grid) <- TRUE

mapview(meuse.grid, zcol = "dist", at = seq(0, 1, 0.25))
```

Note: In the CRAN version this only works for Raster* objects, but I assume that is what you are after.

Comment: I get this error ! :
Error in leaflet::addCircleMarkers(m, lng = coordinates(lst[[i]])[, 1],  : 
  unused argument (at = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example to reproduce the error and also let me know which versions of mapview and leaflet you are using?